# How to see event name in etherscan.io transaction event log?

Tags: solidity, events, etherscan

In etherscan.io, I want to be able to see the event name (signature) in the transaction page event log, like [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa85feaadd51a982c81b994b1716241f9b31e6b72162205e4a1a11fda771d7ba2#eventlog). 
Currently, I don't see it [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x036c8c7a50a2a27e9d009fa86313789017d72b3b191639c2252ea1dd82b9068c#eventlog).

I'll note that the transaction is indeed sent to a verified contract, etc.
Is it possible this is a feature enabled only on mainnet?

Edit: I do see an event signature in Ropsten, for example [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x9872f49dd1cb1530dbde4d8ccaa143f6ec7f28f63599fbd72af9525e5b558695#eventlog).
So I'm interested to know the difference between the two occurrences...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might have to use the logs associated with the contract itself, rather than with the transaction.

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x6cfaa7d8d8e135eee50369fa76e1021e2fd891cd#events

In this case it's `KeyRevealed()` you're presumably looking for.

Unsure why things work this way for the test nets.

Comment: After some lookup, I see there are events in Ropsten which show the logs, example: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x9872f49dd1cb1530dbde4d8ccaa143f6ec7f28f63599fbd72af9525e5b558695#eventlog.
So I'm still looking for a way to be able to view it...